# I'm getting error when I'm compress the image using Bitmap in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bitmap

I'm capturing image using intent and send to my server but when i'm capturing image and compress then some mobile I'm getting bitmap.compress error. 
So how to solve this problem guys
 this is my Code

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 8;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), options);


        File f = new File(fileUri.getPath());

        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        ImageView image = new ImageView(I_kycActivity.this);
        image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(250, 250));
        image.setMaxHeight(400);
        image.setMaxWidth(400);
        image.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        if (phototype.equals("Photo")) {
            img_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            txtphote.setText(f.getName());
            imgUrl.add(f.getPath());
        }
```

and error is

> 12-30 15:33:23.485 9564-9564/com.riya.product.intranet W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
>   12-30 15:33:23.487 9564-9564/com.riya.product.intranet W/System.err:     at com.riya.product.salestracker.I_kycActivity.previewCapturedImage(I_kycActivity.java:1124)
>   12-30 15:33:23.488 9564-9564/com.riya.product.intranet W/System.err:     at com.riya.product.salestracker.I_kycActivity.onActivityResult(I_kycActivity.java:1257)
>   12-30 15:33:23.488 9564-9564/com.riya.product.intranet W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6919)
>   12-30 15:33:23.488 9564-9564/com.riya.product.intranet W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4174)
>   12-30 15:33:23.488 9564-9564/com.riya.product.intranet W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4221)
>   12-30 15:33:23.488 9564-9564/com.riya.product.intranet W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
>   12-30 15:33:23.488 9564-9564/com.riya.product.intranet W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1583)
>   12-30 15:33:23.488 9564-9564/com.riya.product.intranet W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>   12-30 15:33:23.488 9564-9564/com.riya.product.intranet W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
>   12-30 15:33:23.488 9564-9564/com.riya.product.intranet W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
>   12-30 15:33:23.488 9564-9564/com.riya.product.intranet W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   12-30 15:33:23.488 9564-9564/com.riya.product.intranet W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
>   12-30 15:33:23.488 9564-9564/com.riya.product.intranet W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
OutputStream outputStream = null;
```

with

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
```